# Is there anything to actually see in Srebrenica?

Tags: bosnia

I'm in Sarajevo and considering a visit to Srebrenica, where there was an [attempted genocide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srebrenica_massacre) (link to Wikipedia). I know there's a memorial, but is there anything else to actually *see* there? Specifically, historical sites -- eg related to the genocide, the Balkan wars, etc.

I've been to other places where there were massacres /attempted genocides. For example, the killing field at Choeung Ek and the S-21 museum in Phnom Penh together can take a full day to see. But if the memorial at Srebrenica is just a monument, and there's nothing else to see, I'm not sure it's worth the effort of getting myself there and back.

(Note: I can decide for myself if I *should* go there, or it it's "worth" seeing. I just want to know what, if anything, there *is* to see.)

Comment: I'm not asking if I should go, just what is there to see. I can decide for myself if I should go. :-)

Comment: A simple Google search for [srebrenica tourism](https://www.google.nl/search?q=srebrenica+tourism) does not show much. Galerija110795 has a [permanent exhibition](http://galerija110795.ba/exhibitions/) about the massacre, and you can even [book a tour](http://www.sarajevofunkytours.com/bijambare-caves-lake-and-nature-worlds-first-bosnian-authentic-ethno-beys-village-day-tour/tours/25/srebrenica-never-forget-srebrenica-11071995.html) to visit the village.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is opinion based and wanta. I might want to see the road sign saying welcome to srebrenica. You might not.  Nevertheless that would still count as something to see for me.

Comment: Is there such a sign? Most cities here in bosnia dont appear to have them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Srebrenica) here's the list of sights:

> Srebrenica-Potočari Genocide Memorial and Cemetery. For the rest there is nothing much. You can see the place were the Dutch soldiers were stationed. The village itself is not very interesting, but you can actually stop with your family here on a small 2-to-4-day vacation and just enjoy nature and the rich history of this area. Srebrenica seemed to be a quite an important city in Roman era.
>   And there is also the spa, which has around 40 springs of healing water, some of which are good for people who suffer from anemia, skin diseases and some other diseases.
>   People mostly come here to show respect to Muslim (Bosnian 7,000-8,000 killed or missing) victims.
>   In Bratunac some 10 km from Srebrenica, there are many smaller Serb monuments for the victims of war.

Perhaps the [Sase Monastery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sase_Monastery)  from the 13th century might be interesting. I am unaware of any Roman sites.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured was the case, that beyond the memorial and cemetery it's just a regular village (with a sad history, albeit, but a normal village nonetheless.)